# Размеры камеры под различные разрешения экрана 2D

Tags: unity3d

В общем встречал эту проблему раньше, наткнулся на нее и сейчас. А именно при разработке 2D игры, когда нужно обозначить края коллайдерами или разместить по краям прочие объекты и при этом чтобы скеил игровых(не UI) объектов происходил под размеры текущего экрана, а не указанного лично вами в Unity(например вы поставили **1080:1920**, а у игрока **1080:2340**).

В ответе я привел код, где мы запоминаем начальные значения размера экрана и меняем уже в `Update()`, если размер был изменен(можно в `Start()` запихнуть).

Вроде вопрос не сложный, но дойти до такого не каждому дано...

---

### Update

Метод работал только при изменении размера экрана. Добавил скрипт на вызов изменения скеила в `Awake()` для статичных разрешений.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

### Динамическое изменение окна игры

```
private float _defaultHeight;
private float _defaultWidth;

private void Start()
{
    _defaultHeight = Camera.main.orthographicSize;
    _defaultWidth = Camera.main.orthographicSize * Camera.main.aspect;
}

private void Update()
{
    Camera.main.orthographicSize = _defaultWidth / Camera.main.aspect;
}
```

---

### Скеил размера камеры в Awake

```
private float _startAspect = 1080f / 1920f;

private float _defaultHeight;
private float _defaultWidth;

private void Awake()
{
    _defaultHeight = Camera.main.orthographicSize;
    _defaultWidth = Camera.main.orthographicSize * _startAspect;

    Camera.main.orthographicSize = _defaultWidth / Camera.main.aspect;
}
```

Значения в `_startAspect` это ширина и высота экрана, которую вы использовали в редакторе юнити.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]